# Как сделать текст сбоку картинки через CSS?

Tags: css3, css

Надо через css сделать так, чтоб текст отображался полностью сбоку, от самого верха и до низа картинки, и начинался с новой строки, только когда места у картинки уже не было.

Я пытался через css сделать так, вписал вот такой код:

```
img{ text-align: right;}
```

Но ничего не вышло.

Comment: Почитайте внимательнее любой учебник по цсс тегам - там это классические примеры =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
img {float: right;}
```

Comment: +1, только ему скорее всего нужно img{float:left;}, хотя могу ошибаться.