# Как создать такой div? (html css)

Tags: html, css

Начал недавно изучать html и css. Не подскажете как создать подобный div, как на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, допустим. смешно)

Comment: Вот: `<div><img><p>Текст1</p><p>Текст2</p></div>`

Comment: Имеется ввиду как расставить элементы внутри подобным образом

Comment: Каким «подобным»? Ничего не понятно

Comment: все тут понятно.

Comment: @Инквизитор автор сошёл с ума?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, см. ответ =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так.

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

p {
  background-color: wheat;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img alt="Картинка" />
  <p> some text some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text</p>
  <p> some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Воот! Благодарю. Хоть кто-то на этом форуме сохранил остатки интеллекта.

Comment: @Bitchdragon это называется попытка угадать, что имел в виду автор. И для базы знаний угадывания это очень плохо. И вопросы, и ответы должны содержать чёткие описания в текстовом виде. Поэтому минусы от меня вам обоим за нанесение вреда базе знаний

Comment: И если внятно сформулировать вопрос и вбить его в поиск, то окажется, что уже здесь был как минимум один раз, например: [Как сделать текст сбоку картинки через CSS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/85534)

Comment: @andreymal, я не угадывал, мне из мокапа все было понятно (и похуже видал). На минус мне хвостом накласть, не кармодрочерствую, но хотелось бы уточнить ваши ожидания по "чётким описаниям в текстовом виде". С моей точки зрения ответ самоочевиден, но я не утверждаю, что стопроцентно прав.

Comment: @Инквизитор это не вам «все было понятно», а ваша интерпретация картинки случайно совпала с тем, что автор имел в виду на самом деле. Почему на картинке отображён сырой html-код, хотя в [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423184) автор html-код не рисовал? Почему `</p>` находится не под картинкой? Почему div изображён в виде квадратика со стрелочкой, а не в виде html-кода? Почему картинка изображена в виде `<img>`, а не в виде квадратика? В какой момент должно заканчиваться смещение текста вправо — сразу под картинкой или только после закрытия первого тега `<p>`?

Comment: Не надо домысливать за меня, ладно? Это вас не с лучшей стороны выставляет. Человек только учится, скорее всего не по голому HTML, а по пособиям с иллюстрациями, вот и нарисовал, как видел. В предыдущие вопросы лазить - слишком жирно, если вам это надо (пусть даже и ради отстаивания своей точки зрения в данной беседе), то мне - нет.  Да, другой вариант - картинка и первый абзац в две колонки, под ними третий абзац, но вероятность этого оцениваю ниже - то, что я предложил, относится к более начальному уровню, исходя из всех виданных учебных ресурсов. Будьте проще, в общем. Бритва Оккама, да.

Comment: @Инквизитор вот вы уже начали размышлять «вероятностями», а это верный признак того, что вопрос должен быть закрыт как непонятный.

Comment: @andreymal, кому надо, тот поймет. Хотите - голосуйте за закрытие, главное, автор получил, что хотел.

Comment: @Инквизитор подобные рассуждения неприемлемы в базе знаний

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137427/discussion-between--and-andreymal).